# Flashbots - Bundle simulation always reverts

Tags: go-ethereum, golang, flashbots

I have a series of transactions I'm trying to bundle in golang.

several of the transactions are signed transactions from a range of different wallets that are not yet submitted to the mempool.

When I simulate the bundle all the transactions revert with no further information given as to why.

However if I simulate the transaction data in Tenderly they all succeed. I have also tried submitting all the transactions to the mempool and skipping the bundle/simulation and they too succeed.

Is there something I could be missing here?